# Do I have to create my MYSQL tables again in Heroku when deploying? - Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, heroku

I have a quick question if someone could help me I would appreciate it.

I am doing the deploy of my NodeJS website with Heroku, my website uses MYSQL, where the tables I used to develop the website are. Do I need to create these tables again in ClearDB in Heroku to deploy the website? Isn´t there a way for Heroku or ClearDB to use the tables I had already created in MYSQL during the development? Thanks!!

Comment: What framework are you using? 

In Symfony there is a bundle called doctrine/migrations.
You basically create code which updates your database. And you can execute this code on deployment on every environment. Every env has its own database. So yes, you need to create it again.

Comment: this seems to be something similar for NodeJs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-migrate

Comment: Im using NodeJS and Express. Not sure what Symfony is.
Okok thanks! I will create the tables again then. Thanks for the info

Comment: you should use that npm package. this will make your live easier